# How to test django app without giving an app_name

Tags: python, django, testing

My project structure looks like this: `backend/src/apps/app_name/tests/foo.py` and when I'm trying to run the tests by entering a command `python manage.py test` it runs 0 tests. The only correct way to test is `python manage.py test src.apps.app_name` but I'm to lazy to do it with every app.

Comment: Is `app_name` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`? By default it looks in the installed apps.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is: `src.apps.app_name`

Comment: but what is the "root" of the project. Where is the `manage.py` located?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in `backend`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
backend/src/apps/app_name/tests/foo.py
```

to

```
backend/src/apps/app_name/tests/test_foo.py
```

Make sure all your test files and functions start with `test`

Comment: is app_name in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: like I told above, the INSTALLED_APPS string looks like `src.apps.app_name`

Comment: Show me, please. It's not `src.apps.app_name`, just  `app_name`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PQ80VC1q
a path must be included because it doesn't see the app

Comment: It should only be `players`. There is something wrong then

Comment: Are src and src/apps proper python modules or just directories? Meaning, do they have `__init__.py` files?

Comment: @Melvyn dude, I forgot about this. you saved my life, thanks. you can also tell me how to include an app to INSTALLED_APPS without giving a full path, of course if you know. :D

Comment: Well, if all your apps live in src/apps, you could add that to `sys.path`, but I'm not a fan, as you can end up with ./foo and src/apps/foo and then not understanding why src/apps/foo isn't working. You're already using apps as part of your module path that is shading django.apps...You may not want to add to the confusion. :)